# Qt Quick 2 - How to get the QTableView delegate content from c++ model?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, model, qtquick2

In one of my projects, using Qt Quick 2, I created a `TableView` view which draws custom items. The item template was defined in the `delegate` property of my table view. The qml code of the item template is something like that:

```
Component
{
    id: itGridItem

    Item
    {
        width: gvMessageGrid.width
        height: itemTextID.height + 40

        Rectangle
        {
            property int messageWidth: (gvMessageGrid.width / 2) - 50

            id: itemRect
            x: senderIsMyself ? 25 : gvMessageGrid.width - (25 + messageWidth)
            y: 5
            width: messageWidth
            height: itemTextID.height + 20
            color: senderIsMyself ? "#d5d5d5" : "#800b940e"
            radius: 5
            clip: true

            Text
            {
                id: itemTextID
                width: parent.width - 20
                text: itemText
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                textFormat: Text.StyledText
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font.family: "Segoe UI Emoji"
                font.pixelSize: 18
                anchors.margins: 10
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.top: parent.top
                color: "#101010"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my c++ code, I also created a class inheriting from `QAbstractListModel`, which I linked with my view using the `model`property of my `TableView` view.

In this c++ class, I need to access several properties defined in the above shown item template, as an example I need to get the value of the `font.pixelSize` property declared in my item template's `Text` child component.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: That sounds like a dependency in the wing direction, the model should not know about the view (now should the c++ layer know about the QML). What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to also print the content of my view to a PDF file. However the PDF content must remain editable, e.g the exported texts must be able to be selected and copied to clipboard. To achieve that the only way is to paint the item content in the printer canvas, inside the c++ code. I know that the content of my item may be grabbed to an image, but this is not a solution for me, as the PDF looses the important features I mentioned above in this case.